# Any way to improve performance using LIKE '%something%'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say I have a table with a varchar(max) column containing big amounts of text. It could be something like e-mail bodies or logs.

I'm doing look-ups like this:

```
SELECT text 
FROM table
WHERE text LIKE '%whatimlookingfor%'
```

When the table contains millions of rows, this becomes rather heavy. How can I improve the performance of these type of operations when normal indexing is not helping?

Comment: Look up `contains` and full text indexing:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx.

Comment: I don't think an index would help with your current query because the pattern begins with a wildcard.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - That's why `FULL TEXT SEARCH` is introduced